# ParserError when trying to compile ERC-20 smart contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I am new to Solidity, and as an exercise, I am trying to create an ERC-20 token.

However, I am encountering an error, and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

The error I am getting is

> ParserError: Expected '{' but got 'function' -->
> scripts/erc20.sol:33:5: | 33 | function symbol() public view returns
> (string) | ^^^^^^^^

The error is resulting from the part of the code that is calling the ERC-20 interface to implement its functions (code pasted below for reference).

Can anybody advise on how I can resolve this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
   //ERC Token Standard #20 Interface
 
contract ERC20Interface {
    function name() public view returns (string)
    function symbol() public view returns (string)
    function decimals() public view returns (uint8)
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256)
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance)
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining)
 
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value)
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value)

}
```

If you want to see the full erc20.sol file, here it is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
 
//Safe Math Interface
 
contract SafeMath {
 
    function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }
 
    function safeSub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a);
        c = a - b;
    }
 
    function safeMul(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a * b;
        require(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    }
 
    function safeDiv(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }
}
 
 
//ERC Token Standard #20 Interface
 
contract ERC20Interface {
    function name() public view returns (string)
    function symbol() public view returns (string)
    function decimals() public view returns (uint8)
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256)
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance)
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining)
 
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value)
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value)

}
 
 
//Contract function to receive approval and execute function in one call
 
contract ApproveAndCallFallBack {
    function receiveApproval(address from, uint256 tokens, address token, bytes data) public;
}
 
//Actual token contract
 
contract LizCoin is ERC20Interface, SafeMath {
    string public symbol;
    string public  name;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint public _totalSupply;
 
    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;
 
    constructor() public {
        symbol = "LIZ";
        name = "LizCoin";
        decimals = 2;
        _totalSupply = 100000000;
        balances[0xD4aA67f778Bba2805bC122F18F3d61Df59C7A542] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), 0xD4aA67f778Bba2805bC122F18F3d61Df59C7A542, _totalSupply);
    }
 
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
    }
 
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }
 
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
 
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }
 
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
 
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }
 
    function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes data) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        ApproveAndCallFallBack(spender).receiveApproval(msg.sender, tokens, this, data);
        return true;
    }
 
    function () public payable {
        revert();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the erc20.sol file?

Comment: Sure thing, I will update the original post

Answer (score 0):

```
contract ERC20Interface {
    function name() public view returns (string)
    ...
```

Changing the "contract" to "interface" and adding semicolons should solve the issue.

```
interface ERC20Interface {
    function name() external view returns (string memory);
    function symbol() public view returns (string memory);
    function decimals() public view returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining);
 
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! I tried changing "contract" to "interface" as you suggested, but I'm still getting the same error unfortunately on line 33 :(

Comment: @whizwang I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @trizin! That resolved the above issue. However, a new error came up with the totalSupply function.

Comment: Would you know how to resolve the new error? The new error I'm getting is ParserError: Expected '{' but got 'constant' --> scripts/erc20.sol:74:35: | 74 | function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint) { | ^^^^^^^^.

Comment: Your contract seems to have even more issues. Perhaps it's meant to be used with an older version of solidity. Please see here for an up to date version: https://www.north-47.com/knowledge-base/erc20-token-smart-contract-for-ethereum-blockchain/